# Circular imports on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Well, I'm trying to set up `fileA` which has functions from `fileB`. Inside `file B` i use some variables from `file A`. It's something like this:

```
fileA
import fileB
a = []
fileB.function1()
```

and file B is:

```
fileB
import fileA
def function1():
 fileA.a.extend([2, 3])
```

but i get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'fileB' has no attribute 'function1'
```

I know there are multpiles question about the same thing, but i have not seen anyone having an error like this, and until now I'm unable to find a solution

Comment: You need to move shared methods/variables to a third file like `fileC` and use them in both `fileA` and `fileB`

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using shared variables for this at all. Have you learned about function arguments and return values yet? You should almost certainly be using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @brunodesthuilliers how would you do avoid circular dependencies in this case?

I'd first question why f1 wants to call a function in f2 that wants to touch a variable in f1. Since all we have here is a toy example out of any context, it's impossible to give a one-size-fits-all answer, but there are at least three main solutions:

#### 1. move f2.function back into f1.

If both need to know each other so intimately, why separate them ?

f1.py:

```
def function():
   a.extend([2, 3, 4]])

a = []
```

f2.py

```
import f1
f1.function()
print(f1.a)
```

#### 2. move the call to f2.function in another module f3

so f1 doesn't have to know about f2.

f1.py

```
a = []
```

f2.py

```
import f1

def function():
   f1.a.extend([2, 3, 4]])
```

f3.py

```
import f1
import f2

# this is really ugly... spooky action at distance.
f2.function()
print(f1.a)
```

#### 3. change f2.function so it takes `a` as argument

so f2 doesn't have to know about f1

f1.py

```
import f2
a = []
f2.function(a)
```

f2.py

```
def function(a):
    a.append([2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use local imports in this case instead of global ones. I've seen many of this in the source code of OpenStack.

f1.py

```
import f2
a = []
f2.function1()
```

f2.py

```
def function1():
  import f1
  f1.a.extend([2, 3])
```

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but it's the worse advice one could give. The proper solution is to avoid having circular dependencies at all.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how would you do avoid circular dependencies in this case?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed bad, but if the worlds leading open source Python community uses that, I believe them as that is the best thing that one can do in this situation.